# Why do I get an error “no module named lal”, when there is clearly a directory named 'lal'?

Tags: linux, python

When I enter certain commands at the command prompt or in the python interpreter, I get an error message, no module named lal. But there is clearly a directory called lal in the same path from which I am running the command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIFku.png)

Answer (score 3):

The directory doesn't actually contain a Python module, though. Look inside – it has no `__init__.py` or any other Python files whatsoever.

[Looking inside,](https://github.com/lscsoft/lalsuite/tree/master/lal) the actual module files aren't in `lal/` but actually at `lal/python/lal/`. You cannot import them as-is, however, because the module is SWIG-based so it needs to be compiled (and installed) before use.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please clarify what I need to make this work? I am a newbie in this. I have been following these instructions <http://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/workflow/pycbc_make_psd_estimation_workflow.html>  and I get the error 'no module named lal' when I enter pycbc_make_psd_estimation_workflow on command line and press enter. I have tried 'pip install lal' and 'import lal' etc. at various levels in the file structure.

Comment: The instructions needed for PyCBC _itself_ seem to be at https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/index.html – it seems that you've used Docker method and your terminal screenshot is inside Docker, but it's unclear which Docker image you're actually using. If you want to use `pip`, the instructions have that as well, but it's meant to be used _outside_ Docker (and it by default installs from the network, not from the local files).